# How Do I Resolve IP Collisions Over VPN

Tags: vpn

My laptop's speed, as reported by speedtest.net, is around 50MB down and 50MB up.

When I connect to my wife's small company VPN, the speed suddenly drops to less than 1MB down and 3MB up.

According to her company's IT support staff, other people connecting to the VPN don't report similar issues. In other words,

- My laptop works great when it's *not* connected to the VPN
- My laptop works horribly when it *is* connected to the VPN
- Other peoples' laptops work great when they are connected to the VPN

One theory of the IT staff is that there is an IP collision. My home gateway's IP is 192.168.0.1, and the corporate gateway is also 192.168.0.1, so I know that's definitely a duplicate IP. I don't know if there's any others.

Nothing is reporting any type of duplicate IP (although I don't know if anything would be). I also don't know why a duplicated IP would cause a *slowdown*; it seems like it would either work or it wouldn't.

For giggles, I tried changing the laptop to a manual IP of 192.168.3.250, which seems unlikely to exist on the corporate network. Everything worked, but the speeds over VPN were still horrible. Of course, that wouldn't resolve the 192.168.0.1 duplicate IP issue.

I'm not sure the "IP collision causing horrible slowdowns" is the cause. But I'm trying to rule it out since it would either fix the problem or prod the IT staff to look for something else. But I can't figure out a way to resolve the issue without changing my home network's IP range to something weird like 192.168.128.0/22.

Another theory is simply that there's a broken hop on the route from my house to the VPN endpoint, which would explain things, but that would suck because how do you fix THAT?

One other thing to add: as a test, I disable IPv4 on my laptop, forcing everything to use IPv6. I connected to the VPN using its IPv6 address. The speed issue seemed to be resolved, but I don't know if that's because it removed an IP collision or because it takes a different route that bypasses the broken hop. But using IPv6 only is a poop show - so much stuff breaks.

Comment: `there's a broken hop on the route from my house to the VPN endpoint, which would explain things, but that would suck because how do you fix THAT?` you use tracer route to track down broken hop and then contact appropriate owner of that hop

Comment: I've actually had to do that before, years ago. Problem 1 is identifying who the owner is of a hop. For example, who owns "ord08s13-in-x0e.1e100.net"? Problem 2 happened when I was lucky enough to track down the owner, and it's obviously a huge company providing backbone services and they wouldn't even talk to me because I wasn't "their customer".

Comment: `ord08s13-in-x0e.1e100.net` owned by `1e100.net` and you can find contacts via whois service, also you can ask your provider to contact them as well, showing traces as evidence

Comment: The last time this happened, it was the typical catch-22: my provider (correctly) said it's not their problem but with with the provider of that hop and they have no more sway than I do; the provider of the deficient hop (semi-correctly) said they're not providing services directly to me so I'm not the customer, the next hop down the food chain is. Maybe I'll have more luck this time, but it seems like providers are mostly looking for chances to point the finger elsewhere.

Answer (score -2):

Resolving IP collisions over a VPN requires careful troubleshooting and configuration adjustments. Here's a step-by-step approach to help you resolve IP collisions in a VPN setup:

- Identify the IP collision: Determine which two or more devices are experiencing the IP collision. Look for error messages or indications of connectivity issues that can help you pinpoint the problem.
- Verify VPN configuration: Check the VPN configuration on both ends of the connection to ensure that there are no overlapping IP address ranges. Make sure that the IP address ranges used in the VPN are unique and do not conflict with any existing networks.
- Check DHCP settings: If your VPN uses DHCP (Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol) to assign IP addresses, ensure that the DHCP server is correctly configured and not conflicting with other DHCP servers in the network. Make sure the DHCP scopes or address pools are unique and properly defined.
- Change IP addresses: If the conflicting IP addresses are within your control, you can change the IP addresses of the devices in conflict. Assign unique IP addresses to each device, ensuring they fall within the correct subnet and are not overlapping with any other devices or networks.
- Implement subnetting: If changing IP addresses is not feasible, consider implementing subnetting to divide your network into smaller, non-overlapping subnets. This allows you to create separate IP address ranges for different segments of your network, avoiding collisions.
- Update VPN settings: Modify the VPN settings to reflect the changes made in IP addresses or subnets. Update the VPN configuration on both ends to ensure they match the new IP scheme.
- Restart devices: After making changes to IP addresses or subnet configurations, restart the devices involved in the collision. This helps ensure that the devices obtain the new IP addresses or recognize the new subnet assignments.
- Test connectivity: Once the devices are back online, test the connectivity between them over the VPN. Verify that they can communicate without any IP conflicts and that all network services are functioning as expected.
- Monitor and troubleshoot: Keep an eye on the network and monitor for any further IP collisions or connectivity issues. If the problem persists or new collisions arise, investigate the network topology, configurations, and address assignments to identify any potential misconfigurations or overlaps.
  If you're still experiencing difficulties in resolving IP collisions over a VPN, it's recommended to consult with a network administrator or IT professional who can provide more specific guidance based on your network setup and requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the checklist, but unfortunately many of the troubleshooting steps are either things that are re-stating the problem I've having (e.g. Identify the IP collision), things I've already tried (e.g. check for duplicate DHCP, change IP address, restart devices) or things that require the type of wholesale network configuration change I'm trying to avoid (e.g. "implement subnetting").

Comment: This answer seems to have been generated by ChatGPT. This is not allowed as per the guidelines.